# kmscon and deadkeys

Tags: keyboard, xkb, dead-keys

How can I configure `kmscon` to use dead keys? I already have `xkb-layout=br` in `/etc/kmscon/kmscon.conf`, but the dead keys don’t work. (`'` + `e` gives me `e` instead of `é`). The layout seems to have been loaded, since the `ç` key works.

Is it a bug in `kmscon` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is still missing functionality.  There is an [open issue on Compose support](https://github.com/dvdhrm/kmscon/issues/118) and a [proposed patch](https://github.com/bluetech/kmscon/commit/89aeb0f6cbabf928ec9526d8c92138a42d48c61a).

According to the commit log, this example should allow functional deadkeys:

```
$ kmscon --compose --xkb-layout=us --xkb-variant=intl --xkb-options=ralt:compose
```